# Xcode IDEBundleInjection 'Error Accessing Bundle'

Tags: xcode, xctest

Here's a sample test case off of Apple's auto generated code:

```
@interface TransformationTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation TransformationTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testExample {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass");
}

- (void)testPerformanceExample {
    // This is an example of a performance test case.
    [self measureBlock:^{
        // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
    }];
}
```

Any test fails because of the following issue:

```
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error accessing bundle '<>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Transformation-epxdcmceeyrkpqaqhckucbknydvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TransformationTests.xctest'
DevToolsBundleInjection environment:
XCInjectDiagnostics: (null)
XCInjectBundleInto: <>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Transformation-epxdcmceeyrkpqaqhckucbknydvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Transformation.app/Transformation
XCInjectBundle: <>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Transformation-epxdcmceeyrkpqaqhckucbknydvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TransformationTests.xctest
TestBundleLocation: <>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Transformation-epxdcmceeyrkpqaqhckucbknydvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TransformationTests.xctest
TMPDIR: <>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C55DBC49-3E15-4424-AB04-8F080B3DFB44/data/Containers/Data/Application/9166EE1F-741D-4E34-8ECE-F048215B84CC/tmp
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: <>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Transformation-epxdcmceeyrkpqaqhckucbknydvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH: <>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Transformation-epxdcmceeyrkpqaqhckucbknydvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks


*** Test session exited(1) without checking in. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/d7/_7pl6k7d7nz6k0vhw3d8tnqm0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-05-15_15:07:22-jSYNZc.log
```

In the derived data folder, the xctest folder is missing; and I am unsure how to ask Xcode to generate it for me. Any pointers?

EDIT: My best case solution was to create a new project. :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution - clear the derived data directory. Worked for me. :/